# Using forward slash as ID attribute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Just discovered that you can use (any?) unicode character as ID attributes, and this opens up a whole new world for my part.

But I'm trying to set the ID attribute to `/name` , and it doesn't want to work. Here's what I've got:

http://jsfiddle.net/z2xkm9pr/

```
#\\/name\\/ {
    display:none;
}
#\\/name\\/:target {
    display: inline-block;
}
#\\/name\\/:target ~ .open {
    display: none;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this something impossible to achieve? Do I have to go back to using  ☠ ?

ALSO: 
In my final CSS I'm using `[id*='work-']` to select all divs with the ID work-, how do I use /name for this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What "new world" is this opening up?

Comment: Skulls in the address bar man, cmon! No, actually I'm working on a one page navigation site and I've been trying to find a way to hide the hash in the address bar. The only problem is that once I do that, the section can't be accessed by a first time user. So instead of removing the hash, I was thinking to incorporate it into the URL and make it look decent. @MikeBrant

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An [`id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) value may, according to HTML5 and in browser practice, contain any characters except space characters. This gives a lot of liberties, but choices have their cost, since contexts where `id` attribute values might be used outside HTML may impose their own restrictions and requirements.

Specifically, in CSS, an [identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) (such as one that you write after `#` in selector syntax) “ can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit”. Other characters may be used only using escape notations that use the backslash `\` character.

In your jsfiddle, the HTML attribute is `id="#\\/name"`. This means that the attribute value starts with one `#` character, followed by two `\` characters, followed by one `/` character. All these must be escaped. The simplest way is to precede each of them with a backslash, so the selector would be `#\#\\\\\/name`.

But I suppose that the `#` in the value is actually a typo or mistake and should not be there. So I think your code was meant to be like this:

```css
#\\\\\/name {
    display:none;
}
#\\\\\/name:target {
    display: inline-block;
}
#\\\\\/name:target ~ .open {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="\\/name">I'm alive!</div>
    <a class="open" href="#\\/name">Open</a>
</div>
```

Comment: So there's no way to just use the `/name` as an ID and have the URL just to show `example.com/#/name` Thank you for a really pedagogic answer. As said, just discovered this function! (This site never seizes to impress).

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that you wanted just `/name`. Yes, you can use it, and you can have `href="#/name"`. No escaping needed. In CSS, it needs to be escaped, e.g. using a selector like `#\/name`.

Comment: And if I want to use it with [id*='idname'] do I just go `[id*='/name']` or `[id*='\/name']` ?

Comment: It suffices to write `[id*='/name']` since here `/` is not part of an identifier.

Comment: I see. Kiitos my friend! I've really learned something today.